# Listening for data entry

Tags: asp.net, .net

There are two applications:

```
1) A C++ application that was written by a third party supplier and communicates with an SQL database.  We cannot modify the source.
2) An ASP.NET web application written in house (VB.NET)
```

A user starts to enter information (forename and surname) about a person into the C++ application form.  We want the web application to open; populate the text boxes (first name and surname) and execute a query.  The web app is built and will perform the required search if a user types in the forename and surname manually.

Is there a way to do this without changing the C++ application.  I am wandering if I can use some sort of listener e.g. windows service?

Comment: what does "web application to open" mean?

Comment: @Igor, Internet Explorer to open on the screen.